# Optimize map contains

Tags: scala

I have the following condition

```
if (map.contains(clazz)) {
      // .....
}
```

Where map is defined as `Map[Clazz,String]`

And `Clazz` is defined as

```
case class Clazz(key: String, field1: String, field2: String)
```

However, the `key` field alone identifies the object, so the comparison of field1 and field2 is redundant. How to optimize the `contains` statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Simple and straight forward way instead of overriding equals and hashCode**

Redefine your `Clazz` like below.

```
case class Clazz(key: String)(field1: String, field2: String)
```

This way equals and hashCode methods will be generated with only key in consideration and field1, field2 will be ignored for the equality check.

That means key uniquely determines the `clazz` instance which is what you want.

Now you can do `contains` check which will only use `key` for internally for equality check.

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> case class Clazz(key: String)(field1: String, field2: String)
defined class Clazz

scala> val map = Map(Clazz("foo")("apple", "ball") -> "foo", Clazz("bar")("cat", "bat") -> "bar")
map: Map[Clazz, String] = Map(Clazz(foo) -> "foo", Clazz(bar) -> "bar")

scala> map contains Clazz("foo")("moo", "zoo")
res2: Boolean = true

scala> map contains Clazz("bar")("moo", "zoo")
res3: Boolean = true

scala> map contains Clazz("boo")("moo", "zoo")
res4: Boolean = false
```

**Other way is to just override equals and hashCode**

```
case class Clazz(key: String, field1: String, field2: String) {
  override def equals(otherClazz: Any) = that match {
    case otherClazz: Clazz => otherClazz.key.equals(key)
    case _ => false
  }
  override def hashCode = key.hashCode
}
```

**Third way is the least recommended way**

Just maintain a `Map[String, Clazz]` key to Clazz map.

Now you can check contains like below

```
val keyMap = map.map { case (clazz, _) => clazz.key -> clazz}

keyMap.contains(clazz.key)
```

When match is successful then you can get the value using the code.

```
map.get(keyMap(clazz.key)) //this will give Option[String]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can re-define `equals` and `hashCode`:

```
case class Clazz(key: String, field1: String, field2: String) {
  override def equals(that: Any) = that match {
    case that: Clazz => that.key.equals(key)
    case _ => false
  }
  override def hashCode = key.hashCode
}
```

Comment: You can, but it is a terrible idea. case classes are generally interpreted to be (immutable) value types. It's not obvious, unless you go and look at its implementation, that they are not in fact value types (a la DDD) but are instead entities.

Comment: I see you point, but I think it very much depends on the domain. If in the OP's domain this kind of equality is not surprising, then it should be fine